# Create logger that prefixes log messages

Tags: python, logging

Let's say I have a client and server class:

```
import logging

class Client:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.logger = logging.getLogger(self.__class__.__name__)
        self.name = name

    def foo(self):
        self.logger.warn('[%s] foo', self.name)

class Server:
    def __init__(self):
        self.logger = logging.getLogger(self.__class__.__name__)

    def bar(self):
        self.logger.warn('bar')
```

How could I make a logger for the client that will take care of the `[self.name]` prefix magically? The only Idea I have would be to set a global format including `%(client)`-prefix and using a custom filter for the `Client`. This seems unecessary complicated and global. I feel like there must be a simple way that I just don't see.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done using the [`logaugment`](https://github.com/svisser/logaugment) library (disclaimer: I made that library to make it easier but this can also be done using the standard library).

Filling in the client's name can be done as part of a logger's `Formatter` which formats the log record into a string and at that step you can prefix the message.

Create a logger:

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger()
handler = logging.StreamHandler()
formatter = logging.Formatter("%(client)s: %(message)s")
handler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(handler)
```

Specify the client's name for this logger (i.e., the value to fill in for `%(client)s` in the above formatted log string:

```
logaugment.set(logger, client='Client')
```

From now on you can call logger methods as normal and the client's name will be filled in automatically:

```
logger.warn("My message")
```

Comment: Do I need to specify the Handler locally for the client logger to apply the Formatter? This seems to prevent that I set the Handler globally (e.g. application decides if log goes to file or stdout).

Comment: @Zulan: if the logger already has a handler, then you can change the formatter of that handler. So you can indeed create the handler globally for all loggers and then modify the formatter later on.

Answer (score 17):

This can be done without any additional dependency using a custom `LoggerAdapter`:

```
import logging

class LoggerAdapter(logging.LoggerAdapter):
    def __init__(self, prefix, logger):
        super(LoggerAdapter, self).__init__(logger, {})
        self.prefix = prefix

    def process(self, msg, kwargs):
        return '[%s] %s' % (self.prefix, msg), kwargs

class Client:
    def __init__(self, name):
        logger = logging.getLogger(self.__class__.__name__) 
        self.logger = LoggerAdapter(name, logger)
        self.name = name

    def foo(self):
        self.logger.warning('foo: %s', 'bar')

client = Client('client1')
logging.basicConfig(format='%(message)s')
client.foo()
```

Which should print

```
[client1] foo: bar
```

Answer (score 7):

Using a LoggerAdapter:

```py
logger = PrefixLoggerAdapter(logger, dict(prefix='username'))
logger.info('hey')  
# INFO [username] hey
```

and this is the class:

```py
class PrefixLoggerAdapter(logging.LoggerAdapter):
    """ A logger adapter that adds a prefix to every message """
    def process(self, msg: str, kwargs: dict) -> (str, dict):
        return (f'[{self.extra["nickname"]}] ' + msg, kwargs)
```

Answer (score 3):

Another solution is to use the ***extra*** dict to specify a prefix.

First, create your logger as you normally would, for example:

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
# Add any custom handlers, formatters for this logger
myHandler = logging.StreamHandler()
myFormatter = logging.Formatter('%(myApp)s - %(message)s') # Note the myApp key here
myHandler.setFormatter(myFormatter)
logger.addHandler(myHandler)
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
```

Note how we added a new key, ***myApp***, in the format. Then from the client we create a LoggerAdapter and specify an ***extra*** dict with a *custom* value for myApp:

```
logger = logging.LoggerAdapter(logger, extra={'myApp': 'Client'})
logger.info('All your base are belong to us')
```

This will print:

```
Client - All your base are belong to us
```

Similarly, from the server you can log as follows:

```
logger = logging.LoggerAdapter(logger, extra={'myApp': 'Server'})
logger.info('All your base are belong to us')
```

This will print:

```
Server - All your base are belong to us
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to use something like PrefixedLog, wrapping log instance, in C# world, but in Python world logging is configured differently (instead of passing an instance, it seems common to call `getLogger` and rely on handlers defined for your library).

Vitaly's answer good, but it fails if you try to chain adapters, because `logging.LoggerAdapter` does not inherit from `logging.Logger`. My solution is this:

```py
import logging

class PrefixedLogger(logging.LoggerAdapter):
    def __init__(self, prefix, logger):
        prefix = "[{}]".format(prefix)

        #hack because LoggerAdapter in not inherited from Logger
        if isinstance(logger, PrefixedLogger):
            inner_prefix = logger.prefix
            inner_logger = logger.logger
            prefix = "{} {}".format(inner_prefix, prefix)
            logger = inner_logger

        super(PrefixedLogger, self).__init__(logger, {})
        self.logger = logger
        self.prefix = prefix

    def process(self, msg, kwargs):
        return '%s %s' % (self.prefix, msg), kwargs
```

Answer (score 0):

Another method is to update the current handlers to have a new format.
This adds a pytest function name to the output:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="function", autouse=True)
def setLoggerPrefix(request):
    ''' add the test name to the logging messages '''

    # Prepare the test name.
    testName = request.function.__name__[len("test_"):]

    logger = logging.getLogger()
    myFormatter = logging.Formatter('%(levelname)s:[' + testName + '] - %(message)s')

    # Set each logger to have this new format
    myHandler = logging.StreamHandler()
    myHandler.setFormatter(myFormatter)
    for handler in logger.handlers:
        handler.setFormatter(myHandler)
```

Output now looks like:

```
INFO:[validate_page] - <some message here>
INFO:[validate_page] - <some other message here>
PASSED                                                                   [ 14%]
------------------------------ live log teardown ------------------------------
INFO:[validate_all_pages] - <some teardown message here>

tests/application/test_users/test_create_users.py::test_create_users
------------------------------- live log setup --------------------------------
INFO:[create_users] - <some message here>
INFO:[create_users] - <some other message here>
..
```

Answer (score 0):

The LoggerAdapter only applies to the messages issued directly to the logger and not those from child loggers.

If you instead want to apply the prefix to all log messages coming from an external module, you can do:

```
import logging
class PrefixFormatter(logging.Formatter):
    def __init__(self, prefix, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.prefix = prefix
    def format(self, record):
        if record.name == "externallib" or record.name.startswith("externallib."):
            record.msg = f"{self.prefix}{record.msg}"
        return super().format(record)
    
handler = logging.StreamHandler()
handler.setFormatter(PrefixFormatter("externallibprefix:"))
root_logger = logging.getLogger()
root_logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
root_logger.addHandler(handler)

# in the "externallib" library
logging.getLogger("externallib").info("from externallib")
logging.getLogger("externallib.sub").info("from externallib.sub")

# in the main script
root_logger.info("from main")
```

This does not change any handlers registered by the external library itself.